# What's a good XML viewer/editor for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, development, xml

I use [XML Editor from XMLmind](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) for editing/viewing XML file in Mac.

It's not bad, but I expect an XML editor for Mac. What options do I have including the commercial/free software?

Comment: Are you just editing XML specific to the Mac (like 'plist' and 'sdef') or are you editing a variety of schemas?

Comment: @Philip : I wanted a general solution to parse the XML files.

Comment: Obligatory: [vim](http://www.vim.org/) is good enough for me!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### OS X Software for Editing XML

- [EditX](http://www.editix.com/) (commercial)
- [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) (commercial)
- [XML Edita](https://www.coxone.com/xmledita/index.html) (commercial)
- [XMLMate](https://wiki.macromates.com/Main/Plugins) (free/open source
  plugin) for [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (shareware)
- [XMPlify](http://xmplifyapp.com/) (commercial)

Comment: Of the many mentioned here, which is your recommendation? Which is better featured? Which is more Mac-like in behaviour?

Comment: Please repair the link to [EditX](http://www.editix.com/download.html) that now is not free. Linked is an old version for PowerPC

Comment: ONE colud also use the new Visual Studio Code Editor (my favorite Editor by now) or Atom or MacVIM or Xcode,Netbeans,Eclipse,IntellijIDEA (basically any Programming IDE does also Support XML Syntax Highlighting and most of the also have Code Completition) if you need also DTD/XSD Validation the you need to take a closer look

Comment: oXygen.  Worth every dollar.

Comment: URL of XMLMate is dead.

Comment: The most Mac-like, by far, are Xmplify, then XML Edita, in that order.

Answer (score 9):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) works on Mac OS and it is one of the best XML editor around, actually. It has XSD validation, autocompletion towards this schema. Also, it offers a graphical XSD designer.

Comment: Just to add: `Ctrl/⌘` + `Shift` + `F` will format the XML.

Answer (score 8):

Although it's still a beta I have found [Xmplify](http://xmplifyapp.com/) to be a pretty useful XML aware tool. Copes with DTD, XSD, XPath and XSL transformation in the tool

Comment: Out of beta now, $59.

Answer (score 5):

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is overall a good IDE, it's available on Mac, and it [supports editing XML](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/xml_editor.html) in ways such as syntax highlighting, collapsing a given scope, and validating XML. I haven't used it much for XML, but I've had good experiences with that IDE for other purposes so thought I would mention it here.

Comment: Allows folding/collapsing elements to more-easily view the structure and change the order.

Answer (score 5):

And of course Emacs with psgml-mode or nxml-mode will edit XML.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 3):

Testing this and that, I settled down with [Text Wrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/), with [XML Tidy](http://www.bergspot.com/blog/2012/05/getting-xml-tidy-xmllint-to-work-on-textwrangler-4-0/) script. It's free and pretty useful for my purposes.

Comment: XML Tidy does indentation ... and I believe it checks well-formedness. Apparently xmllint, which the XML Tidy script uses, *can* validate. Can you validate XML using XML Tidy within Text Wrangler?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Apple Developer Tools installed, then you have Xcode and this includes the "Property List Editor" application (Apple plist files are in XML format, hence the name).

You can find the application here:

```
/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Property List Editor.app
```

Comment: I don't think the Property List Editor can deal with generic XML files, it's intended to edit a specific .plist format.

Comment: ^ This is true (what ghoppe said). And even now that it's integrated into Xcode, no longer standalone, you just get the raw color coded code with line numbers. No disclosure triangles, etc. like a _.plist_ file gives you.

Comment: Well, Xcode complaint on an XML not being in the right format. So... it's not exactly generic.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple and free software to view, no editor: [XML Spy](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/xmlspy/id1254478180?l=en&mt=12)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.    See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: @fsb thanks, my suggestion is based that is program is free and simple, fit well for me :)

Comment: That's good but it doesn't tell us anything about the software, why you like it, how it will fit the needs of the OP, etc.  We prefer answers to be more than just 1 line.  See [answer] for tips.

Comment: @fsb the top-rated answer here just rattles off a list of software, with not "tell[ing] us anything about the software, why you like it, how it will fit the needs of the OP, etc." It's not fair to hold Jonas to a different standard than those who have been here a long time.

Comment: @Conrad I’m holding Jonas to the same standard according to the [help].  Site users can downvote answers that don’t follow the site rules, regardless of how long the author has been here.  I was trying to help Jonas improve his answers.  You question really belongs on the [meta] site and you’re free to address it there.

Answer (score 1):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com).

You can download the source code from GitHub and compile it locally. Then in the preferences install the appropriate *language bundle*. https://github.com/textmate/textmate

If you like the application I would recommend buying the commercial version to show your support to the author.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to XMLmind XML Editor there's [QXmlEdit](http://qxmledit.org/) It is also free and quite feature rich. It's written in Qt and runs on Mac as well as the other platforms Qt supports.

Answer (score 1):

I always believe that an open source is the best and simple solutions. You can try [BlueFish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html), or [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), I strongly advise you to try it, you won't lose anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing, and I just came across [XMLmind XML Editor.](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) I like how it can load my files pretty quickly.

@rds: I've tried using Eclipse to open my XML files, but it would hang with my files (>15MB).  I've come to notice any editor built with Java hangs upon trying to open my file, or at least takes an unbearably long time to load it.

Comment: The OP already mentioned XMLmind.

Comment: Also, XMLmind is Java, so shouldn't it hang as well, @jde?

Answer (score 0):

I like the look of http://www.sublimetext.com/2
as seen in a Daniel Shiffman tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Microsoft VS Code with an XML extension...

I'm using:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml

You can <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type "XML" to find the utils provided by the extension.

Some keyboard shortcuts are provided, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to format nicely.

Or find elements by XPath query, or display the XPath of the highlighted element.

Answer (score -2):

You can try [all in one JSON viewer](http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer) or [all in one XML viewer](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer).

[image]

Comment: Other than the links being swapped (The JSON link goes to the XML viewer and the XML link goes to the JSON viewer), why has this been downvoted? 

I have used both of these to beautify code for publication many times.

Comment: I guess even though the question asks for a viewer/editor, reading the question they really want an editor.