# Is it possible to validate XML in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xml

I need to validate XML. I know that Xcode has some support for XML, such as highlighting and collapsing. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to run actual **validation** of XML from within Xcode. There are other XML tools that can do this that are available on Mac, as mentioned in this [broader posted question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/whats-a-good-xml-viewer-editor-for-mac-os-x), but I was just curious about Xcode specifically.